Why did the Númenórean dissenters associate Míriel's use of a palantír with darkness or evil?
In The Lord of the Rings: The Rings of Power S02E03 "The Eagle and the Sceptre," some Númenóreans oppose Míriel's ascension to the throne, considering her use of a palantír as "dark magic" and "Elf sorcery." This reaction puzzles me, given the Elves' reputation for opposing Morgoth, the embodiment of darkness and evil.
During Míriel's coronation, Númenóreans divided, with those opposed to her rule angered upon discovering her use of a palantír, derisively referred to as an "Elf-Stone." This raises an intriguing question about the perception of Elven artifacts and magic in Númenor.
Elves have long been known for their battles against Morgoth, the "Dark Enemy" or "Black Foe." So why would an Elven creation be associated with darkness and malevolent sorcery?

Because Amazon, apparently.  Though even in the books, things connected to Elves was not exactly considered positive in the later days of Numenor.  Not ‘darkness’, but not good in their eyes either.

Because they terk err jerbs?

It's also a political move to demonise the Faithful, who are not mistrustful of the Elves. The people claiming this (was it Belzagar? Pharazôn?) don't need to believe it themselves. Everything that happens in Númenor from here on has a deeply political angle.

For several reasons, primarily because, as established in the first season, the general Númenórean population have turned against the traditional ways of their past and have grown resentful or at least distrustful of elves, as seen in their reaction to Galadriel’s arrival.
There’s support for this in The Silmarillion, which tells us the men of Númenor (and Ar-Pharazôn in particular) grew envious of the elves. This was because Númenor was within sight of Valinor — or at least the last island before it — but they knew they weren’t allowed to sail there, and didn’t know what happened to men after death.

 Pharazôn is shown to harbour this sentiment, and for the same reason, in The Rings of Power, though not until a couple of episodes later, in “Halls of Stone”.

Elves have not been to Númenor for a long time, perhaps long enough for a generation or two to have passed, even though Númenóreans live much longer than most humans. Certainly the King seems older than anyone else we see there.
Second, the palantír was hidden away and Míriel did not tell the population she had it, or used it, or what for. Any secret counsel would be seen as suspicious when she has made a choice to do something unpopular.
Finally, if there was any doubt, when Elendil tries to pick it up there’s a flash of light that flings him across the room. (Note that the compression of time in Rings of Power means it’s unclear how long the palantir has been on the island, but the implication as mentioned above is  at least a generation, so maybe before Elendil’s time.) Magic, certainly the flashy kind with fireballs and lightning bolts, is not common in most of Middle-earth, and this would be alien and frightening to humans — especially a society who has been out of contact with elves for so long.

"it seems to shock Elendil when he tries to pick it up" Hwaet?! Elendil was the one who loaded them on his ship and brought them to middle earth. The more I hear about this series, the more SMH. Also the King's men did not go to the North, so the people there would have been The Faithful for the most part.

I thought the Palantirs were Numenorean artifacts, created by them.

@Stian nope. Gifted to them by Elves.

Definitely made by the Elves, possibly Feanor himself, though that was unconfirmed.

@Yorik when I say “shock”, I mean in the episode he bends down to pick it up and there’s a flash of light and he’s thrown across the room. He’s not emotionally shocked, and indeed is one of the few Numenoreans already identified as an “elf friend”.
